# Jetpack compose webview calculation of measured height

Tags: javascript, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

`val calculatedHeight = contentHeight * scale - viewHeight`

contentHeight: document.body.scrollHeight

scale: displayMetrics.density

viewHeight: webview.measuredHeight

I am using the above formula to calculate my scrollable height of my webview. Is there a way to use injected javascript into my webview to calculate webview.measuredHeight instead?